# Get notified when user pastes from clipboard

Tags: android, clipboard

My app can copy a sequence of texts to clipboard. Currently, the user goes to my app, selects "copy item 1", goes to another app and pastes the text, goes back, selects "copy item 2" etc.

Is there a way to get notified when the user pasted the first text so I can directly add the next text to the clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
    getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
```

Then add a listener for clip changes `addPrimaryClipChangedListener(ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener what)` from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html#ClipboardClasses)

I think this is fired when there is changes in the clip data (presumably that will happen on paste), but I've never tried it.